# iOS 9 Facebook login simulator -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, ios9, app-transport-security

I've updated to Xcode 7 and the latest iOS SDK. I've added the appropriate entries in my app's plist:

[image]

My app's Facebook login works fine on device. However, on iOS 9 simulator, I'm getting:

`-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"`

And login is not working. I've seen [facebook login issue - canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663382/facebook-login-issue-canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-error-null) but I have FBSDKCoreKit framework. I've also seen [Facebook SDK 4.5 IOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991525/facebook-sdk-4-5-ios-9) but it's answer doesn't solve my problem.

Why am I getting this error on simulator and not on device even though I've done the checklist at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9?

Comment: I have same question.
Do you have solution?

Comment: There seems to be a bug with the iOS Simulator cause it works on the device as expected!

Comment: Exactly the same thing here but I do notice that if you leave the SafariViewController window (which is blank in my case) up long enough it eventually crashes SafariViewController with the following message: 'UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.uikit.viewservice.com.apple.SafariViewService was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid.}'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Why do I see console messages like 'canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb...://' or ?

> This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned
>   false. As long as you have configured the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`
>   entry in your plist as described above, **you can ignore this warning**.

Comment: This error only appears in the simulator not if you run your app on the device

Comment: same problem i cant login in fb in ios 9

Answer (score 9):

This is not a problem. The FB SDK is trying to open the native facebook app which has the fbauth2:// url type. In Simulator its not available, so its just putting a log that it could not open the native Facebook app. You can configure the Facebook acct in Simulator and then tell the FB Login button to use the native Facebook account instead of opening the web view. But Facebook contends that millions of people use Facebook in browser and so in iOS 9 they have used the new SFSafariViewController as the default behaviour for facebook logins even on devices. You can try to use the native Facebook and see if it works.

Check this link for the discussion.

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fbugs%2F786729821439894%2F%3Fsearch_id

Comment: The error message is misleading. It says `canOpenUrl` failed, not that it can't open the url.

Answer (score 4):

After you have updated your App's `.plist` file with the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array, which you seem to have already done:

**Next**, verify that your **Facebook SDK** is version **4.6.0**. Follow the [Facebook directions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) if it's not.

**Lastly**, which is probably where the problem arises, is to  **Reset** your Simulator's content and settings

### To Reset your Simulator:

1. Choose **Simulator**
2. Select **Reset Content & Settings**
3. and the **Reset** option

Apple's Simulator, even the IDE, will have bugs and closing and reopening, along with reseting the simulator, are always something to consider early on in your search for a solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: or you can just delete your app from the simulator, works also

Answer (score 3):

I downgraded my Facebook SDK from version 4.7 to 4.5.1 and worked fine on both Simulator and iphone device(without Facebook app installed).

Comment: I've also considered that, but I'm using Parse and it depends on Facebook SDK, and manually downgrading Facebook SDK may be dangerous in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook:

> iOS SDK supports SafariViewController which lets us switch show
>   web-rendered dialogs instead of doing an app-switch. This beta SDK
>   will automatically determine the best app switch experience for people
>   based on their device. For example, defaulting the person's experience
>   through SafariViewController instead of Safari for Facebook Login....

Facebook reference link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/?search_id

Stack ref link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32593070/2905967

Answer (score 0):

By following these steps, you may be able to avoid this error:

1) go to -> Supporting File

2) info.plist

3) Right click on info.plist -> Open As -> Select Source Code

*** Add code below inside `<dict>...</dict>` ***

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: how do I add an array by itself into a property list file? it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: You can accomplish this by adding a key/value pair LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as an ARRAY and then add two STRINGS inside Item 0 with a value of fbapi and Item1 with a value of fbauth2. However, I have the same problem as the OP and adding fbapi didn't fix it for me. Same error.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9  Still you are getting then refer this link.

Answer (score 0):

1] Authentication in Developer.facebook and generate Facebook Id like :=>460481580805052

2] Set Bitcode : No From Build Settings

3] Set up Plist File

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb460481580805052</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>460481580805052</string>

<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2 </string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
</array>
```

4] Download 4 Sdk Framework like

```
=>Bolts.framework
=>FBSDKCoreKit.framework
=>FBSDKLoginKit.framework
=>FBSDKShareKit.framework
```

Answer (score 0):

please use LSApplicationQueriesSchemes  or addd into plist your app id .

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 9 or above, add this method in your AppDelegate file:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43515243/535013