# Error in facebook login, IOS 9, Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my app. But getting an error.
My info.plist code is :

```
   <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb_APP_ID</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>APP_ID</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>APP_Name</string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

And i am getting this error :

```
2015-10-24 11:38:11.177 APP_Name[3553:150778] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
2015-10-24 11:38:11.190 APP_Name[3553:150778] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Facebook login is happening but getting this error too. Any way to resolve this? I've googled a lot and couldn't fix it. I am using Parse and facebook both. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I prefer no warning message thing. Is there any way to get rid of it??

Answer (score 2):

I came to the same conclusion, but had other issues on the path to this error message which may be helpful for others - so sharing here.

I used **Parse v1.9.0** with the **FBSDK v4.7** & **Xcode 7.0.1**.  I was following **Rob Percivals iOS9 & Swift 2** course on [udemy.com](http://udemy.com). (lecture 131).

He had used earlier versions of the sdks - his zipped up code worked, but I got the fbauth2 errors.  When I tried to use the latest sdks, I couldn't even get as far as the errors.

The **Parse v1.9.0** downloads have a file missing: **ParseStarterProject-Bridging-Header.h** - without it, none of the import statements work.

The **Parse AppDelegate** tells you to follow Facebooks instructions for setting everything up on the FB site & populating your **info.plist** file, then uncomment a line in the missing header file.

I created a **ParseStarterProject-Bridging-Header.h** from scratch & put the import statements in for **PFFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h** & **FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h**.

Also note that when you unpack the **Parse v1.9.0** starter project, it doesn't contain all the frameworks, so make sure you unpack the **Parse Library** zip and then drag into your project. Ditto for Facebook.

At this point, I thought everything would work - it didn’t.  Still lots of red error messages. When I looked at the **“issues navigator”** it couldn’t find the **FBSDK**, **ParseFacebookUtilsV4** or the header file I’d created. They were all in the navigation pane, so I was totally confused.

The key/solution was in the **Targets Build Settings**.

Under Search Paths:
**Always Search User Paths** - I set this to **YES** - default was **NO**.

**Framework Search Paths** - You should have a pointer to your project, but need to add one to your **FBSDK** location. It should be **/Users//Documents/FacebookSDK** if you followed the recommendations.

Swift Compiler - Code Generation:

```
Install Objective-C Compatibility Header = YES

Objective-C Bridging Header = ParseStarterProject/ParseStarterProject-Bridging-Header.h
```

Took me a while to get the right syntax here - if you used the **ParseStarterProject** and put the header file in the same group as your **AppDelegate** and **ViewController** - the above should work for you.

The default **PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()** line provided by parse for uncommenting didn’t work for me - kept showing an error, so I replaced with a variant of the test code provided by Facebook. Worked like a charm - still got the fbauth2 errors, but now got to the fb login screen & connected.  That's when I discovered the fbauth2 error messages didn't have a negative effect - you can ignore them :)

If you have been struggling with Parse & FB integration - hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You can ignore the message...

**@Jonathan Hornby @joan16v:** I had the same issue but placing the code in an action button (not in the viewDidLoad method) worked for me.

BTW: You don't need a *bridging header* anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears only when you are using simulator, not when you use a device.

Since your info.plist is ok, you can ignore it.

Check this answer: [iOS 9 Facebook login simulator -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676334/ios-9-facebook-login-simulator-canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-erro)