# Facebook integration authorization error using swift for iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to add the login feature thru facebook sdk 4.15 .I followed the facebook sdk developer notes but i am getting error..

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
 canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
 Failed to get remote view controller with error: Error 
 Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo=
  {OriginalError=Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"}
```

**Edited**
I have tried many times with editings. Now working fine but still with two  messages

```
 canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
 canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

[image]

why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

This means your app isn't allowed to query for the fbauth2:/. Add the fbauth2:/ in LSAPPLICATIONQUERIESSCHEMES.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html

Comment: I have edited my questn and added my screen shots for plist file. its added there but still same problem facing..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676334/ios-9-facebook-login-simulator-canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-erro Duplicate