# Why login with facebook in project not accessing token

Tags: ios, facebook

It worked fine to login with logInWithReadPermissions in iOS 9 by adding FBDSK file manually, but by using cocoapods its not working and giving error like .

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Comment: hello yogita. take a look on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33718324/5349267

Comment: https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/1ad78c7d17051c36f60b934b64725f31 just open this link and compare your .plist file with this file